# Matching people with similar rating?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, matching, rating-system

Suppose you have a collection of people with a sample size of 10,000. Each person in the collection has a rating score in the form of a winning percentage: **0.00 < x < 1.00**.

Currently my system randomly picks two people and matches them together. I would like to improve matchmaking by pairing up people who have a high winning percentage with others that have a high winning percentage.

Have you ever played World of Warcraft arenas? Typically if you are in 2000 bracket you are matched with teams who are in 2000 bracket. If you are in 1500 bracket, you are matched with people who have similar ranking.

What is the the easiest way to implement such matchmaking system? While implementation doesn't really matter, even a pseudo-code would help, but I would greatly appreciate if you can guide me in the right direction using JavaScript, Backbone, and Underscore as a toolbelt.

Comment: Why are you matching based on winning percentage and not some kind of [Elo system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system)?

Comment: @AlexQueue Elo is a rating system not a matchmaking system. I've already used Elo, but decided to remove it and use just win/loss ratio instead. Elo ratings were closely co-related with win/loss ratio, so there was little point to keep it around if I could simply write the entire rating system as: `wins / wins + losses`. Simpler.

Comment: I meant using Elo as a rating system. Have you modeled what peoples win/loss ratios will look like once you get a good matchmaking system in place? Because once you do, win/loss will start to deviate from Elo. Say for example I'm in the 70% percentile. Playing a random distribution of people I'll come out with a win/loss of .7. If you match me with people of my skill level, my win/loss will fall towards .5. With a good matchmaking system, everyone's win/loss will go to .5, even as their Elo ratings stay the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place everybody in a balanced binary tree (if you'll be frequently adding and removing people) or in a sorted array (if the data set is more or less static), using their winning percentage as the sort key.  To match somebody, locate them in the tree or array, then match them with somebody within, say, +/- 10 rankings using a random number generator (e.g., if you're using an array and the person is in the ith index, then match them with the person at the i + rand(10) + 1 index).

I'm assuming that somebody's winning percentage will only change by small increments, which means that updating the tree or array will usually be a constant time operation since you'll just be swapping adjacent elements.